# Retrieving date in numeric form (5 digits); how to convert to regular date format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, clarity

I have two dates that are numeric:
A. **65495** and
B. **65496**

The dates are supposed to be:
A. **04/26/2020** and
B. **04/27/2020**

I have tried this code:

```
select convert(varchar(25), cast(cast(tbl.mydate as integer) as datetime), 120) [newdate]
from tbl
;
```

But I end up getting these dates:
A. **2079-04-27 00:00:00** and
B. **2079-04-28 00:00:00**

I am using clarity database on SQL-Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
select dateadd(day, <your value>, dateadd(day, -65495, '2020-04-26'))
```

This calculates the base date on the fly.

Or, you can be explicit:

```
select dateadd(day, <your value>, '1840-12-31')
```

That is an unusual epoch date.

Comment: if i wanted to do time, could it be like this:  cast(dateadd(MINUTE, cast(tbl.mytime as int), dateadd(MINUTE, -70500, '2020-04-26 19:35:00')) as time) [newtm]  if time was 70500 = 7:35 PM

Comment: @hanbanan . . . I don't understand your comment.  Perhaps you should expand it to a new question.